# How to show line numbers for all buffers, windows & tabs

Tags: vimrc

Is there any way to show line numbers by default, for all windows, buffers, and tabs opened inside Vim (including man pages, `netrw` buffers, etc.)?

What I have already tried to edit `_vimrc` by putting `set number`. This changes the behavior of the all new file buffers. But while I am opening a man page or navigating a directory listing using `netrw` or `NERDTree`, the line numbers are not showing up. And for each kind of those windows, buffers and tabs, I have to run `:se nu`. Are there any way to enable Vim to show up line numbers for all its buffers?

---

*Why do I need this?*

I am very new to Vim and try to adopt its culture. Previously, I was using [Epsilon — a EMACS-style text editor](http://www.lugaru.com/) editor for a long time. But, some time ago, I found [this question at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218390/797393) and was very astonished to see [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/797393) and started to learn Vim.

Now, in my previous editor these are easy settings for me, what my eyes are very familiar with. And I believe there must some way to do this in Vim too.

---

Can anybody help me or at least give me some hint to get this setting done?

Comment: One question per post, please. Either split up your post, or ask how to apply your general settings to netrw/NerdTree buffers.

Comment: @muru: those are very similar and perhaps...would guide me to the same same direction...

Comment: Exactly. So why post as if these are two wildly differing things?

Comment: @muru: perhaps not...may be the questions are divided into...but it also ends up with one conclusion...as those are `slightly different` in nature and that is why those are split likewise...

Comment: yet your title is combined.

Answer (score 6):

From  [mMontu's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6440/5912), to my another similar question.... that this can easily be solved by adding below line in `vimrc`:

```
au BufWinEnter * set number
```