# How to show non-printable characters for all buffers, windows & tabs

Tags: vimrc

Is there any way to show non-printable characters by default, for all windows, buffers, tabs, opened inside Vim (including man pages, `netrw` buffers, etc.)?

Additionally I also like to see the non-printable characters for all the buffers. And here goes my `_vimrc` lines for that:

```
    scriptencoding utf-8
    set listchars+=space:·
    set listchars=eol:¶,tab:» ,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:·
    set list
```

And again, this is working for all the file buffers. As soon as I open up a manual page or `netrw` directory listing or `NERDTree` buffer, I have to run `:se list` for each buffer.

Can anybody help me or at least give me some hint to get this setting done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `'list'` on all the windows by using the following:

```
augroup setList
   au!
   au BufWinEnter *  set list
augroup END
```

The (long) explanation of why it doesn't work only by setting it on the vimrc can be found at `:help local-options`.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the light...now i can understand...how to use `au`...and how implement as well....

Comment: @Cylian Glad I could help :)